# How to select the last three rows of a table in ascending order?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to select the last three rows of a table in ascending order. What is the query for that?

Comment: How do we determine which rows are "last" in the table; i.e. what column or set of columns defines the sequence of rows in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: Logically the last three rows for a column in ASC order would be the first three in DESC order. +1 kgb

Comment: this way you are going to get the right rows, 3 rows is not much to sort not using mysql

Comment: then, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ASC LIMIT (FOUND_ROWS() - 3), 3" should work for you(though i didn't test it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM tblname
        ORDER BY rowid DESC
     ) WHERE rownum < 4;
```

`Rowid` is the physical address of every row.
`Rownum` is the psuedo column which is used to generate sequence number of rows.

Comment: Assuming that \`rowid\` and \`rownum\` are columns in \`tblname\`, and there is some kind of relationship between the columns, this query might return the specified result, but unlikely it would be in the specified order. (\`rowid\` and \`rownum\` are pseudo-columns available in Oracle, but which are not available in MySQL.)